# How to multiply column in Sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a column:

```
-0.75640390000 --number1
0.58303570000  --number2
-0.07794400000 --number3
0.00000000000  -- ....
0.58303570000
-0.07794400000
0.42976550000
0.58781540000
0.00909080000
0.58781540000
```

How can I calculate `(1+number1/100)*(1+number2/100)*(1+number3/100)*... etc`?

Comment: What have you tried already? What exactly are you stuck on? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I use ((EXP(SUM(LOG(1 + column / 100)))) but this calculate wrong value

Comment: What value is it providing? What would you consider the correct value? Take a read of the how to ask link that I posted, you'll get a much better answer if you provide all of the information up front.

Comment: I calculete this by useing foreach operator and  result  compare whit ((EXP(SUM(LOG(1 + column / 100)))) and I get two  different result

Comment: Read the link I sent you and edit your original question with more information. We have your data, now show us the results that you're currently receiving and what you believe the correct results to be. Unless you give us a lot more information we're going to struggle to help.

Comment: For what you are using this ((EXP(SUM(LOG(1 + column / 100))))  and what result you are aspecting t

Comment: I want to multiply  this (1+item1 /100)* (1+item2 /100)......where item  is each number from column

Comment: What is unclear in this question?

Comment: What do you mean by number1 and number2? We take number from first row (number1) and number2 is number from next row?

Comment: I think in sql will be formula with do it  ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `number1` is a value from first row and `number2` is value from next row, then use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  col,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as rn
FROM (VALUES
(-0.75640390000),
(0.58303570000),
(-0.07794400000),
(0.00000000000),
(0.58303570000),
(-0.07794400000),
(0.42976550000),
(0.58781540000),
(0.00909080000),
(0.58781540000)
) as t(col)
), rec AS (
SELECT  CAST((1+col/100) as float) as d,
        1 as l
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  d * (1+col/100),
        l+1
FROM rec r
INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.rn = l+1
)
SELECT TOP 1 d
FROM rec
ORDER BY l DESC
```

Output:

```
1,01874941736518
```

**EDIT1**

Challenge with 2 million rows was accepted :) I create table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Testing](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [col] [decimal](19, 11) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_id_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)
```

Put this in it:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  CAST(0.00000000002 as decimal(19,11)) as col, 
        1 as rn
UNION ALL 
SELECT  CAST(col + 0.00000000002 as decimal(19,11)),
        rn+1
FROM cte 
WHERE rn < 2000000
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Testing] ([col])
SELECT col from cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

And then make this:

```
;WITH rec AS (
SELECT  CAST((1+col/100) as decimal(19,11)) as d,
        1 as l
FROM [dbo].[Testing]
WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST( d * (1+col/100) as decimal(19,11)),
        l+1
FROM rec r
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Testing] c
    ON c.id = l+1
)

SELECT top 1 d
FROM rec
ORDER BY l desc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Output was:

```
1.49182491770
```

Query was executed in 16 sec on my local PC.

**EDIT2**

With the help of temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Testing (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [col] [decimal](19, 11) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_id_testing] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
) 

INSERT INTO #Testing ([col])
SELECT Put_Column_Name_Here 
FROM Put_Table_Name_Here

;WITH rec AS (
SELECT  CAST((1+col/100) as decimal(19,11)) as d,
        1 as l
FROM #Testing
WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST( d * (1+col/100) as decimal(19,11)),
        l+1
FROM rec r
INNER JOIN #Testing c
    ON c.id = l+1
)

SELECT top 1 d
FROM rec
ORDER BY l desc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

DROP TABLE #Testing
```

Comment: The output will by one result (1+(-0.75640390000/100))*(1+((0.58303570000)/100).......

Comment: Get it :) Check the answer :)

Comment: How cen you do it if you have 2 000 000 rows? :)

Comment: You probably fail with arithmetic overflow error. :) What exactly is datatype of this column? Is there any indexes on this table?

Comment: It is no problem if we can calculete this in the end we can convert it in decimal(19,11),,,column  type decimal(19,11) ,

Comment: See edit to my answer. It works OK with 2 million records.

Comment: IT is work !!!!! but I tried it on my table but ID is not IDENTITY, like your example,How cen I do?

Comment: You can use temp table just change `[Testing]` to `#testing` in script below and run it. It will be faster than using CTE. After you get result don't forget to `DROP TABLE #testing`

Comment: Cen you write code ? IN my example,this is my code select col from table1 join table2 on table1.id=table2.id and ...???? WHERE col =NUMBER

Comment: I add script. Please, check it.

Comment: In this example id =1,Id=2...3,4,5, etc  Yes? But I have 2 table and like this,select table2.col from table1 join table2 where table1.id=table2.id I must do It  (1+col/100 )*(1+col/100) and how mach will find Do you understand me ?

Comment: Look you ask: *How to multiply column in SQL* and add some formula, I provide you an answer. The last script I provided creates temp table with auto increment id (from 1 to ... whatever `int` value). Then you must INSERT in it ONLY ONE COLUMN with data you need to calculate and then it goes in recursive CTE to do the job. What possible could go wrong? What `table1` and `table2`?

Comment: If my answer helps... at last :) It would be great if you upvote/accept it. :)

Comment: Help me How I do It?

Comment: To upvote press up arrow near answer... and you already found out how to accept :) Good luck! and remember upvotes/accepting answer is a good manner here (if an answer helps you of course)